# Line Break while displaying comment

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

```
{
  "result" : [ {
         "LineNo": 1,
        "CommentLine": "2020.08.25 08:46:27 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08)"
        },
      {
        "LineNo": 2,
        "CommentLine": "2020.08.24 16:49:44 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08) \n2020.08.24"
       },
      {
        "LineNo": 3,
        "CommentLine": "16:48:57 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08) te"
      }
    ]
}
```

```
function (oData, oResponse) {

                    var comment = "";
                    var line = "";
                    var vRegTimeStamp = /(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/g;
                    var vRegEOC = /^[-]+$/;
                    for (var data in oData.results) {
                        line = oData.results[data].CommentLine;
                        line = line.trim();
                        comment += (line.search(vRegEOC) > -1) ? "\n" : "";

                        var n = line.search(vRegTimeStamp);
                        if (n > -1) {
                            count = count + 1;
                            comment += (comment.length > 1) ? "\n" : "";
                            comment += line + "\n";
                            continue;
                        }
                        comment += line;
                    }
```

This is displaying comment as:
[outPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNb7k.png)

I need output as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogb6V.png)

> 2020.08.25 08:46:27 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08)
>
> 2020.08.24 16:49:44 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08)
>
> 2020.08.24 16:48:57 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08)te

I am not getting where I am doing wrong

Comment: It's because of the input; the second element in CommentLine has a " \n2020.08.24 ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**\n** breaks the line. Therefore your output has extra line break in 2nd comment line because it has **\n**

Try to add line after `line = line.trim();`

```
line = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
```

it will solve your problem

**EDIT**

Changed the JS for you. [Here is JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/48wLauq7/)

```
function oResponse(oData) {
    var comment = "";
    count = 0;
    var line = "";
    var vRegTimeStamp = /(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/g;
    var vRegEOC = /^[-]+$/;
    for (var data in oData.results) {
        line = oData.results[data].CommentLine;

        var match = /\r|\n/.exec(line);
        if (match) {
            comment += line;
            continue;
        }

        line = line.trim();

        var n = line.search(vRegTimeStamp);
        if (n > -1) {
            count = count + 1;
            comment += line + "\n";
            continue;
        }
        comment += line + "\n";
    }

   alert(comment)
}


var abc = {"results": [{
        "LineNo": 1,
        "CommentLine": "2020.08.25 08:46:27 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08)"
    },
    {
        "LineNo": 2,
        "CommentLine": "2020.08.24 16:49:44 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08) \n2020.08.24"
    },
    {
        "LineNo": 3,
        "CommentLine": "16:48:57 UTC  CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08) te"
    }
]
}

oResponse(abc);
```

[Output two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POl4C.png)

Comment: that did tick of  removing extra line break but not I get
2020.08.24 16:49:44 UTC CCA Planner - Fab8 (ZPML_PLN_F08) 2020.08.24 instead would  like to have 2020.08.24 in next line

Comment: you want to attach date from 2nd comment to start of 3rd comment?

Comment: Yes. that is what is my expectation. Sorry not so good with regex.

Comment: @SaurabhVerma Edited the answer for you. Please try that

Comment: thanks for help me buddy! but it broke when I had 4th comment/ I attach image on it.

Comment: send your json array with 4 comments. is there more exceptional cases there? send it so i can check

Comment: Please have look @ my jSon https://jsonbeautifier.org/?id=NzIz

Comment: everything working fine brother. check this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yk5e2487/

Comment: I copied your results from link you mentioned, and just added in this fiddle. it's giving totally fine output. you can have a look

Comment: Hello Brother,
I have made document which can give more details
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13ivlDBIXud02dz_bFLAHz4MJKPBsuE4YFQBnVZqDC_8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello Bro! @Shbhan ,
The test I conducted : https://jsfiddle.net/px53z4ha/1/ it fails . Please have look